# kmeans:Required argument 'flags' (pos 6) not found

Tags: python, k-means, flags

I want to compute the lbp's cluster by kmeans. 
first I compute the lbp value in size 8 * 8 every image.
then I use the cv2.kmeans,but It can't work
the error:Required argument 'flags' (pos 6) not found
code:

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This temporary script file is located here:
/home/nel/.spyder2/.temp.py
"""
from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
from skimage import io
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import numpy as np
import cv2

def loadImages(path):
    import os
    imagePaths = map(lambda a:os.path.join(path,a),os.listdir(path))
    images = map(io.imread,imagePaths)
    return imagePaths,images
    
def lbpdesc(imagename):
    radius = 1
    n_points = 8
    METHOD = 'nri_uniform'
    imagename = io.imread('/home/nel/project/pictest/1.jpg')
    gray_image = rgb2gray(imagename)
    lbp_height,lbp_width = gray_image.shape
    grid_rows = 8
    grid_cols = 8
    py = int(np.floor(lbp_height/grid_rows))
    px = int(np.floor(lbp_width/grid_cols))
    E = np.zeros((py*px,64))
    i = 0
    for row in range(0,py):
        for col in range(0,px):
            block =gray_image[row*grid_rows:(row+1)*grid_rows,col*grid_cols:(col+1)*grid_cols]
            H = local_binary_pattern(block,n_points,radius,METHOD)
            E[i,:] = H.ravel()
            i+=1
    return E

if __name__ =="__main__":
    images = {}
    imagePath,imagesed = loadImages("/home/nel/project/pictest")
    for i in range(len(imagePath)):
        images[imagePath[i]] = imagesed[i]
    
    features = {}
    
    for d,x in images.items():
        features[d] = lbpdesc(x)
    featureall = np.float32(np.vstack(features.values()))
    
    codebookSize = 40
    
    iterMax = 100
    term_crit = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS | cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT,10,1)
    retval,bestLabels,codebook = cv2.kmeans(featureall,codebookSize,term_crit,iterMax,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
```

the error:Required argument 'flags' (pos 6) not found.Why, I need your advise.

Comment: Please include the output of "print cv2.kmeans.__doc__" in your question, and version information. It seems **your version of cv2 requires an additional parameter**.

Comment: I get the information that
kmeans(data,k,bestLabels,criteria,attempts,flags[,bestLabels[,centers]])
-> retval,bestLabels,centers

Comment: Why is there "bestLabels" twice in that list? That is probably your error, you didn't specify `bestLabels`, according to that docstring.

Comment: check the kmeans example: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/kmeans.py